# Detecting value change of input[type=text] in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to execute a function every time the value of a specific input box changes. It *almost* works with `$('input').keyup(function)`, but nothing happens when pasting text into the box, for example. `$input.change(function)` only triggers when the input is blurred, so how would I immediately know whenever a text box has changed value?

Comment: So why no bind both `keyup` and `paste` events?

Comment: http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/detect-copy-paste-and-cut-operations-on.html -- Detecting cut/copy/paste events

Comment: @liho1eye `paste` is just one that I thought of, I'd rather listen for a definitive change than have to think of all the different incoming paths.

Comment: @Jeriko That is the only two ways value can be changed (beside the obvious updating via js code).

Comment: You also want to capture Ctlr-X (`cut`).

Comment: ctrl+x and ctrl+v is detected by keyup but pasting can be done mouse as well hence both needed.

Answer (score 491, accepted):

## Update - 2021

As of 2021 you can use `input` event for all the events catering input value changes.

```
$("#myTextBox").on("input", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

## Original Answer

just remember that 'on' is recommended over the 'bind' function, so always try to use a event listener like this:

```
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Why `paste` though? First i thought it does only work if we paste something with `CTRL+V`.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu: direct asignation of values doesn't trigger any DOM event

Comment: Would be even better if using `console.log()` instead of `alert`. Would be very annoying for keyup to `alert`.

Comment: @cytsunny yea sure, alert is annoying, but in this case is an example of the code to be executed on the value change, it really can be any payload you want.

Comment: If i am changing value of input by a function then it is not showing any alert. please help. @AlejandroSilva

Comment: If you right click and paste, this will return the value of the input prior to the paste.

Comment: What about the `cut` and `select` events?! See my answer below

Comment: I edited the answer, to permits scripts and right click and paste just add `input`. `"change paste keyup input"`

Comment: Just noticed the function is performed many times, just `"input"` is required without adding anything else

Answer (score 115):

#### Description

You can do this using jQuery's `.bind()` method. Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/2/).

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<input id="myTextBox" type="text"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myTextBox").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/2/)
- [jQuery.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 16):

Try this.. credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu

for answering my question here: <del>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651811/jquery-keyup-doesnt-work-with-keycode-filtering?noredirect=1#comment38213480_24651811</del>

This solution helped me to progress on my project.

```
$("#your_textbox").on("input propertychange",function(){

   // Do your thing here.
});
```

Note: propertychange for lower versions of IE.

Answer (score 12):

you can also use textbox events -

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" onchange="SetDefault($(this).val());" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">

function SetDefault(Text){
  alert(Text);
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/291/)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Basically, just account for each event:

Html:

```
<input id = "textbox" type = "text">
```

Jquery:

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function() { 
    alert($(this).val());  
}); 

$("#textbox").change(function() { 
alert($(this).val());  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup select", function() {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

select for browser suggestion

Answer (score 4):

**DON'T FORGET THE `cut` or `select` EVENTS!**

The accepted answer is almost perfect, but it forgets about the `cut` and `select` events.

`cut` is fired when the user cuts text (CTRL + X or via right click)

`select` is fired when the user selects a browser-suggested option

You should add them too, as such:

```
$("#myTextBox").on("change paste keyup cut select", function() {
   //Do your function 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input").bind({
            paste : function(){
                $('#eventresult').text('paste behaviour detected!');
            }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: 
https://github.com/gilamran/JQuery-Plugin-AnyChange

It handles all the ways to change the input, including content menu (Using the mouse)

Comment: How do You use it? I include it in my HTML and used $("input").anyChange(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }); But it never got to the console.log line

Answer (score 0):

This combination of events worked for me:

```
$("#myTextBox").on("input paste", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to detect input, keychange, and keypress.

```
$("#myTextBox").on("input", "keyup", "keydown", "keypress" function() {
  alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to detect a change made after the element has been altered programmatically (i.e, with code) then take a look at MutationObserver API:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/04/mutationobserver-api-guide/

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link that attempts to answer the question. Link only answers are **NOT** [recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).