# Hidden input text submit with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript var that returns the value of a input text ID "ven_prod", with the value of "ven_prod" I need to make a search in my database without submiting the page.

I can't use a javascript var in the java code, so i've setted the value in a hidden input text ID "prod_hidden", but I need to submit it to get the value with the java code and make the search...How do I do it ?

```
<input id="ven_prod" type="text" placeHolder="Código de Barras" autofocus>
        <input id="prod_hidden" type="text" value="">

        <script>    
            $('#ven_prod').keypress(function (e)
                    {
                        if(e.keyCode==13)
                        {
                            var table = document.getElementById('tbprodutos');
                             var tblBody = table.tBodies[0];  
                             var newRow = tblBody.insertRow(-1);
                             var prod = document.getElementById('ven_prod').value;
                             var qtd = document.getElementById('ven_qtd');
                             var barra = prod.substring(0, 12);
                             var num = prod.substring(14, 16);
                             document.getElementById('prod_hidden').value = barra;
                             var ref = <%=pd.getProdutosBarra(request.getParameter("prod_hidden")).getPro_referencia()%>;
OR
                             var ref = <%=pd.getProdutosBarra(JS VAR 'barras HERE).getPro_referencia()%>;

                             if(prod.length==16) { 
                               var newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);  
                               newCell0.innerHTML = '<td>'+ref+'</td>';

                               var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);  
                               newCell1.innerHTML = '<td>'+num+'</td>';  

                               var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);  
                               newCell2.innerHTML = '<td>'+qtd.value+'</td>';

                               var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(3);  
                               newCell3.innerHTML = '<td>R$ '+valor+'</td>';

                               var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);  
                               newCell4.innerHTML = '<td>'+barra+'</td>';

                                document.getElementById('ref').value = '6755';
                                document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = './?acao=Img&pro_id=1';
                                document.getElementById('valortotal').value = 'Testando novo valor';
                                document.getElementById('ven_prod').value = '';
                                document.getElementById('ven_qtd').value = '1';

                            } else {

                                document.getElementById('ven_prod').value = '';
                                document.getElementById('ven_qtd').value = '1';
                                alert("Código de barras inválido!");
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: look at [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Yes, I'm not using jquery yet @Pit Digger, but I think that I need to use jquery to do it...

Comment: u can try this link ajax call using pure javascript
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_callback

Comment: @Shashank you can try reading this... http://w3fools.com

Comment: use a simple code: `$('.someClass').submit()`  or `$('#someId').submit()`

Comment: @Ulugbek Komilovich, in this case I can simple use

<script>
function update() {
$('hidden_barra').submit(); }
</script>  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can make ajax call using jQuery as follows. will submit your form data as well along with hidden elements.

```
var form = jQuery("#YourFormID");
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr("action"), 
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Comment: my problem don't is submiting a form with hidden elements, the problem is that I need to recover in java one input parameter without submiting the form...

If I make this call with ajax, the page will reload ? Or I will be able to recover any value with "request.getParameter('id') on java ?

Comment: @LucasSilvadeFreitas, no, if you use ajax the page will not get submitted and won't reload.

Comment: @th1rdey3, How do I call in my page this ajax function ?

Comment: you have to attach it with a event. for example, a button click.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** You can use like that:

```
$("#pro_barras").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
   //$('.someClass').submit();    
   $('#it_is_form_id').submit();   // it call form's submit function
});
```

The piece of code detected when input text change. To more info see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747486/1746258) If you want to customize `form submit` function

```
$('#it_is_form_id').bind("submit", function(){
  //alert("submit");
  // make here simple ajax query
  return false; //<-- it is used so that default submit function doesn't work after above code. 
});
```

Don't forget, all code will be inside

```
<script>
  $(function() {
   // your code must be here
  });
</script>
```

**b)** If you don't want to use `form`, you can do like that:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#pro_barras").bind("change paste keyup", function() {     
            var text = $("#pro_barras").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "yourUrl",
                data: text,
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err); 
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Making simple ajax query:

- [Using `Jquery` post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567149/1746258
- [Pass entire form as data in jQuery Ajax function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019614/1746258)

Answer (score 0):

> value of a input text named "pro_barras"

Are you sure? Look at this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pro_barras">
```

its not the name of the input, its the ID. You can try using this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pro_barras">
```

And now, you can use `$.ajax` to send the request to a new page, where you will request the data from the database. And then you'll write the response, and take it back on the first page.

What it will do depends on how  you use it. I will try to ask you to simply use `serialize()` method by jQuery API, this will let you to create a simple URL param with the data from the form, use it as:

```
$.ajax({
  var data = $('#formid').serialize(); // serialize the form..
  url: "link/to/file.cshtml",
  data: data,
  success: function (datares) {
    $('#resultid').html(datares); // write the result in the element
  }
})
```

If you want to get only the value from that field you can use

```
var data = $('input[name=pro_barras]').val();
```

> without submiting the page.

Your page will have to be submitted when you click on `input type="submit"` button. To prevent that you can use

```
$('#idofsubmitbutton').click(function () {
  return false; // stop execution and stay on page..
}
```

Then the ajax will continue, other method is to remove the `input type="submit"` and use `<button></button>` which won't cause any submission.

> get the value with the java code

This isn't `java` :) Its JavaScript, they are totally different. :)

Comment: I know that its JS, but its the problem, I need to get the information from JavaScript to JAVA without submiting the page...

I need to do a search on my database when the user finish to input the "pro_barras" field, but If I submit the page I will lost a table  created early..I need to get the parameter spelled by the user without submiting the page, but I need to use it on JAVA code..

Like this.

var ref = <%=pd.getProdutosBarra(request.getParameter("pro_barras")).getPro_referencia()%>;

Comment: You might have read `without submitting the page` tag in my answer, it has a `return false` which you need to stop page submission. Or try replacing `input` with a `button` so that form does not reloads..

Comment: I just updated the question with more code...I dont want to send a request to a new page, I only want to get to my server ONE information from ONE input text or input hidden to do a search without losing the table on the page

Comment: -_- so what do you think, Ajax is meant for? Ajax does this job for you! So that you stay on the page and get the results from any other page without having to load it..

Comment: But I don't have other page D:

Comment: Then why not first create it :) Then send the request to it and load the data :)

Answer (score -2):

You could also add a custom attribute to your input element (in Jquery):

```
<input type='text' id='pro_barras' customattr='myCustomInfo'/>

<script>
 var customValue = $('#pro_barras').attr('mycustomvar');
alert(customValue);
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je3LS/)