# jQuery to show alert on form value change

Tags: jquery

I have a button and a canvas. On button press, a new box can be created. Each box created this way includes a form with two input fields: a select dropdown and an integer input field.

I would like to detect any time the value in *any* of the select dropdowns changes. Imagine that the user has pressed the "New Box" button, hence having created three boxes with the above-mentioned form. Whenever they make any change in any of the select options, an alert should pop up.

Since all boxes created have the same `indi-box` class name, and the select tag has a `name` attribute of `chosen_string`, as well as following [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747439/detecting-value-change-of-inputtype-text-in-jquery/8747486#answer-17759257), I came up with the following jQuery snippet:

```
// check for value change in any of the forms
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".indi-box select[name='chosen_string']").on("input", function(){
    alert($(this).val()); 
  });
});
```

However, no alert message pops up. I tried changing my selectors by (1) also including `#canvas`, and (2) only including `select[name='chosen_string']` nothing else but none of these helped.

I placed the full functioning code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6nphuv7b/6/).

Answer (score 0):

The event handler you want is `change` not `input`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".indi-box select[name='chosen_string']").on("change", function(){
    alert($(this).val()); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Fair point! Although it still doesn't show any alert even after changing `input` to `change`.