# JQuery: listen for input in the fields?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the below HTML code, I want to call a function using the ID of the field whenever there is input in the input fields regardless of the input field number.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" id="input1" class="input1"/>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input2" class="input2"/>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input3" class="input3"/>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input4" class="input4"/>
```

Instead of the below, I want to call one function for all.

```
$("#input1").on('input', function () {
    console.log("this is input1");
});

$("#input2").on('input', function () {
    console.log("this is input2");
});

$("#input3").on('input', function () {
    console.log("this is input3");
});
$("#input4").on('input', function () {
    console.log("this is input4");
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting value change of input\[type=text\] in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747439/detecting-value-change-of-inputtype-text-in-jquery)

Comment: Add the *same* class to all the inputs, eg `class="input1 inputlog"` then add your event to `$(".inputlog")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector to target all your inputs `$('input[id^=input]')`.

`input[id^=input]` means that it will work with all inputs where the id of the input starts with `input`

```
$("input[id^=input]").on('input', function() {
  console.log("this is " + this.id);
});
```

```js
$("input[id^=input]").on('input', function() {
  console.log("this is " + this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" id="input1" class="input1" />
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input2" class="input2" />
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input3" class="input3" />
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input4" class="input4" />
```

Comment: Actually, I want if it is input1 then I will somethinglike input++ to do something with input2 for all inputs

Comment: "*actually*" - please don't "actually" in the comments - describe what you *actually* want in the question so you get an answer to what you want rather than what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Many methods. One of them is to select all the inputs and triggers the input method

```js
$("input").on("input", function (e) {
  console.log("this is input", e.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" id="input1" class="input1"/>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input2" class="input2"/>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input3" class="input3"/>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="code" maxlength="1" id="input4" class="input4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `$()` query selector function accepts multiple comma-separated selectors.

```js
$("#input1,#input2,#input3,#input4").on('input', function () {
    console.log("this is input from input 1, 2, 3 and 4");
});
```

Comment: Downvoted for the maintenance. As you can see in the other answers, there are a ton of options to do this dynamically..